# Category slug is getting numbers appended to it

Tags: categories, slug

I have a category Australia and have been experimenting with boboldehampsink import plugin.

After deleting categories and starting over the category Australia now has a slug called 'australia-6'. I just want 'australia' but i cant get rid of the  hypen and 6.

I notice the content table has lots of entries for australia but no slugs so I'm wondering about the db schema for craftcms and how come i have got a stuck slug so quickly?

Answer (score 2):

When you save an entry/category that is supposed to have its own URL, Craft will assign it a unique URI, based on the section/category group’s URL Format setting.

For example, let’s say you have a section called News, and its “Entries in this section have their own URLs” checkbox is checked, and it has this URL Format:

```
news/{slug}
```

When you save a News entry, Craft will assign it a unique URI based on that URL Format. If the entry’s slug is “foo”, then the first URI Craft will try to assign it will be “news/foo”.

However, if that URI is already taken by another entry/category (or some third party element type), Craft will increment the slug and try again:

- news/foo-1
- news/foo-2
- news/foo-3
- etc.

(If incrementing the slug has no effect on the URI – because the URL Format doesn’t actually contain a `{slug}` token – then Craft will simply give up and add a validation error to the element.)

Once it has found a URI that is actually unique, it will update the element’s Slug with the incremented version.

So in your case, when you save a category with the slug “australia” and it becomes “australia-6“, that means that you have 6 other elements that had been saved with the slug “australia” before it, with the same URL Format that your current category has, and so “australia-6” was just the first slug Craft could find that resulted in your category having a unique URI.

To find out which elements your category’s URI is conflicting with, you can go to Entries > All Entries, and search for `slug:australia`, and click through each of your category groups in the Categories tab, searching for `slug:australia` in each of them.

Comment: Thanks Brandon for the detailed explanation. I understand the auto-increment of slug URIs for uniqueness. This is for a category as opposed to an entry but I see categories have slug entries too. The thing is there are no other Australia entries anywhere in the admin interface - but there are entries in the craft_content table or Australia. So I was expecting 'australia-6' to be changeable.

Comment: Actually found the slugs in i18n table and removed them and element ids. This now allows me to recreate Australia slug as desired :)